# Do I have to pick an item to unlock it?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I need to unlock a couple items from Angel Room and Secrets Room so I would like to know if it is enough to see it as I use the D6 or I do have to pick it to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pick up an item to "record" it, it's not enough to see it.